# What is a “part-key”?

Tags: primary-key, relational-theory, terminology, database-theory

I'm a beginner and student with regards to database design. The tutor recently discussed “part-keys”. I am struggling to find any information on what a part-key is, and I suspect it probably goes by another name.

The example we were given in class was this:

> ```
> ACTIVITY(Activity(PK), Fee)
> STUDENT_ACTIVITY(StudentID(PK), Activity(PK))
> ```
>
> **Is the table showing part-key dependency?**
>
> Yes. Since the second determinant (`Activity`) is part of the primary key (`StudentID`, `Activity`).

Is anyone able to give me any further information?

Answer (score 1):

This example does *not* contain a partial dependency to me.

A partial dependency would be if a table column functionally depends on part of the table's primary key, like in this denormalized table:

```
CREATE TABLE student_activity (
   studentid bigint NOT NULL,
   activity character varying(30) NOT NULL,
   fee numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (studentid, activity)
);
```

where `fee` depends on `activity`.

The solution would be to split this table in two parts like in your question.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thanks for the answer. Okay, that clarifies it perfectly. Much appreciated.